# Passing a vector, queue, and pointer to a function

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, function-prototypes

I have a function `myfunc()` which requires the parameters `std::vector`, `std::queue`, and a pointer to a `MyClass` object.

My function prototype is:

```
void myFunc(vector<MyClass*>, std::queue<MyClass*>, MyClass*);
```

I do not know if this is the proper prototype declaration or not.

To call my function, i do the following:

```
myFunc(myVector, myQueue, MyClassObj);
```

Again, im not sure this is entirely correct.

Lastly, my function is the following:

```
void myFunc(vector<MyClass*> myVector, std::queue<MyClass*> myQueue, MyClass* myClassObj)
{
   //do something
}
```

The function is supposed to search for a specific item in the vector. If it is not found, the myClassObj will be pushed to the queue. Otherwise, if the object is found, it will call another function to set the value of one of the parameters of the myClassObj.

Am i doing this correctly?

Thanks,

Comment: What if any problems do you have with your current approach?

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Compiler says "MyClassObj was not declared in this scope `myQueue.push(myClassObj);`"

Comment: @noobgineer, dont you get the resulted queue after the function return ? is that your problem ? if it is, plz google with function call by reference & function call by value.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Correction, I forgot to change the variable name in the function. It compiles fine now after changing it. Note to self, pay attention to compiler output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*The function is supposed to search for a specific item in the vector. If it is not found, the myClassObj will be pushed to the queue. Otherwise, if the object is found, it will call another function to set the value of one of the parameters of the myClassObj.*"

In that case,

- take the `vector` by `const&`
- the `queue` by `&` .....and
- `MyClass` by `&` or pointer if you prefer that

---

```
void myFunc(const vector<MyClass*>& myVector, std::queue<MyClass*>& myQueue, MyClass* myClassObj)
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Do I also change the prototype and function call to follow by reference as well?

Comment: Is there any reason to use references here rather than iterators?

Comment: Well, the OP didn't mention iterators, Rather than use iterators, I will prefer to use `templates`